# splitting on a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string that I want to split using a regular expression.

Input:

```
S1:1- first split begins.s2:1- first split ends.s1:2-second split begins.S2:2-second split ends,S1:3-third split begins.S2:3-third split ends.
```

Output:should be a list containing the expression on which we split

[S1:1-first split begins,s2:1-first split ends,S1:2-second split begins,S2:2-second split ends,S1:3-third split begins.....]

I want to split on pattern `[s/S][1/2]:[0-9][0-9]`
This is what I have, but it gives me an extra line and removes the regex on which I split.

```
import re
text="""S1:1- first Split begins.continue the sentence
       s2:1- first split ends
       s1:2-second split begins
       S2:2-second split ends
       S1:3-third split begins
       S2:3-third split ends """
output=re.split("[Ss][12]:[0-9]*", text)
```

Comment: Can you please add what you want as output.

Comment: Consider splitting this by simply `\n` something like `re.split("\n", text)`

Comment: It is not necessary that it we have a \n. The text could be a one big string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Positive Lookahead `(?= CODE )` in Regex to accomplish this in order to preserve your regex. Your regex will be something like this:

```
\s(?=[sS][12]:[0-9])
```

Complete Code:

```
import re
text="""S1:1- first Split begins.continue the sentence
       s2:1- first split ends
       s1:2-second split begins
       S2:2-second split ends
       S1:3-third split begins
       S2:3-third split ends """
output=re.split("\s(?=[sS][12]:[0-9])", text)
```

Outcome:

```
['S1:1- first Split begins.continue the sentence\n ', 's2:1- first split ends\n ', 's1:2-second split begins\n ', 'S2:2-second split ends\n ', 'S1:3-third split begins\n ', 'S2:3-third split ends ']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure I understand where you want to split this input, but if you want the text that you're splitting on to be included in the output then you need to have a capturing pattern:

```
 re.split("([Ss][1-2]:[0-9]-)\s*", text)
```

result:

```
['',
 'S1:1-',
 'first Split begins.continue the sentence\n       ',
 's2:1-',
 'first split ends\n       ',
 's1:2-',
 'second split begins\n       ',
 'S2:2-',
 'second split ends\n       ',
 'S1:3-',
 'third split begins\n       ',
 'S2:3-',
 'third split ends ']
```

Comment: yes, I want the text I am splitting on to be included in the output. Why do we get an extra blank line in the first position in the output list.

Comment: This is the way split works; from the documentation: "If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the start of the string, the result will start with an empty string. The same holds for the end of the string."  Honestly, after you accepted the look-ahead variant, I don't understand why you don't just use re.split("\n", text); seems like you don't want to split the lines but rather want to make lines out of the text.